# tests are right, but answer is still wrong

Tags: c#

After a botched attempt at solving Euler problem 1 in C# using arrays, I was pointed toward using a single variable being added to only when the conditions of a for() loop are satisfied.  The code is just plain better, but I can't see what I've done wrong.

The goal is to take the first 1000 numbers, find factors of 3 OR 5, and finally sum the factors up.  I'm doing the first 10, which I know to be 23 before trying the full 1000.  The console reads perfect up until the for() loop is finished, when I ask the code for the final answer at the end however, it gives me 33!  How can the code add anything to the sum variable after the loop!!!  Its taunting me...

```
using System;

public class Problem1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        //assign range to evaluate factors and summation
        int maxNumber = 10;

        //test if i is a factor of 5 or 3
        for(int i = 1; i <= maxNumber; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                //WriteLine here to debug, the real magic here is adding i to sum when test is true
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        //and the final answer is?
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        //uncomment below line if running in vbs
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: (3 + 6 + 9) + (5+10) = 33

Comment: put sum =+ i above Console.Write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's "run" your code:

- 1 ? Continue
- 2 ? Continue
- 3 ? Add
- 4 ? Continue
- 5 ? Add
- 6 ? Add
- 7 ? Continue
- 8 ? Continue
- 9 ? Add
- 10 ? Add

Summed, 10, 9, 6, 5, and 3 is 33.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `maxNumber` is also calculated.

Change this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= maxNumber; i++) // i=3,5,6,9,10 => sum = 33
```

To this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < maxNumber; i++) // i=3,5,6,9  => sum = 23
```

Comment: I am an idiot!  I didn't mean to put that there, it wasn't part of the manual calculation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when

```
 maxNumber == 10
```

the selecred numbers are `3, 5, 6, 9, 10` the sum is **33** (not **23**).
General solution could be something like that (*Linq*):

```
int sum = Enumerable
  .Range(1, maxNumber)
  .Where(item => (item % 3 == 0) || (item % 5 == 0))
  .Sum();
```

when `maxNumber == 1000` the answer is `234168`. If you want to *exclude* `maxNumber`, just *subtract 1*:

```
int sum = Enumerable
  .Range(1, maxNumber - 1) // <- subtract 1
  .Where(item => (item % 3 == 0) || (item % 5 == 0))
  .Sum();
```

so the answer for `10` is `23` and for `1000` it's `233168`